# mongodb aggregation framework group by two fields

Tags: php, codeigniter, mongodb, php-mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm querying my database using aggregation and pipeline, with two separate queries:

```
 $groups_q = array(
            '$group' => array(
                '_id' => '$group_name',
                'total_sum' => array('$sum' => 1)
                )
            );

  $statuses_q = array(
            '$group' => array(
                '_id' => '$user_status',
                'total_sum' => array('$sum' => 1)
                )
            );

$data['statuses'] = $this->mongo_db->aggregate('users',$statuses_q);
$data['groups'] = $this->mongo_db->aggregate('users',$groups_q);
```

And I'm getting what I want:

```
Array
(
[statuses] => Array
    (
        [result] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [_id] => Inactive
                        [total_sum] => 2
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [_id] => Active
                        [total_sum] => 5
                    )

            )

        [ok] => 1
    )

[groups] => Array
    (
        [result] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [_id] => Accounting 
                        [total_sum] => 1
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [_id] => Administrator
                        [total_sum] => 2
                    )

                [2] => Array
                    (
                        [_id] => Rep
                        [total_sum] => 1
                    )
            )

        [ok] => 1
    )

)
```

I don't want to query my database twice. Is there is a better way to do it?
How can I accomplish it with one query? Should I use $project operator?

Comment: are you querying two different collections here? can you explain a little more about what you're trying to do?

Comment: I'm querying the same collection and grouping it by two different fields (status, and by group_name). I'm trying to get the same result as I provided, meaning combination by group and separately by status but in one query.

Comment: I think this will require two queries

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can't use a single `aggregate()` to do two grouped counts with your desired result format.  Once the data has been grouped the first time you no longer have the details needed to create the second count.

The straightforward approach is to do two queries, as you are already doing ;-).

#### Thoughts on alternatives

If you *really* wanted to get the information in one aggregation query you could group on both fields and then do some manipulation in your application code.  With two fields in the group `_id`, results are going to be every combination of group_name and status.

Example using the `mongo` shell :

```
db.users.aggregate(
    { $group: {
         _id: { group_name: "$group_name", status: "$status" },
         'total_sum': { $sum: 1 }
    }}
)
```

That doesn't seem particularly efficient and lends itself to some convoluted application code because you have to iterate the results twice to get the expected groupings.

If you only wanted the unique *names* for each group instead of the names + counts, you could use [`$addToSet`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation/addToSet/#grp._S_addToSet) in a single group.

The other obvious alternative would be to do the grouping in your application code.  Do a single `find()` projecting only the `group_name` and `status` fields, and build up your count arrays as you iterate the results.