# Here is some issue for sorting insensitive sort by in mongodb

Tags: php, mongodb, codeigniter

On performing the below operation,

```
$this->mongo_db->order_by(array('first_name' => 'ASC'))->get('users');
```

the records starting with `A-Z` come before the records starting with `a-z`.
I want them to be sorted alphabetically irrespective of their cases.

e.g. AaBbcCDd....Zz

Comment: what exactly your question, you want to code review?

Comment: I want to a-z and A-Z sort both at same time.

Comment: but i got first A-Z and after a-z

Answer (score 1):

This is because MongoDB, for one, does not have case insensitive indexes ( https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-90 ) and for two (the reason why it doesn't) is because it does not have collations yet ( https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1920 ).

Derick Rethans, one of the PHP driver maintainers, recently wrote a blog post with a possible solution to natural language sorting, http://derickrethans.nl/mongodb-collation.html but it still requires a separate field

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because the [ascii](http://www.asciitable.com/) values of `A-Z < a-z`.

You need to use the [$toLower](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toLower/) function in the aggregate pipeline as below,

- `Project` an extra field for each record to hold the `first_name` in
  lowercase.
- `Sort` based on the projected field in ascending order.
- `Project` the required fields.

The Code as acceptable in the mongo shell:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
{$project:{"users":1,"first_name":{$toLower:"$first_name"}}},
{$sort:{"first_name":1}},
{$project:{"users":1,"_id":0}}
],{allowDiskUse:true})
```

If your business permits to store the `first_name` field value in either lowercase or uppercase, you can avoid this problem. And more importantly you can index the `first_name` field and query, in the case, that the `first_field` is stored.

As requested, please find below the code in PHP:

```
$proj1 = array("users" => 1,'first_name' => array ('$toLower' => '$first_name'))
$sort = array("first_name" => 1)
$proj2 = array("users" => 1,"_id" => 0)
$options = array("allowDiskUse" => true)
$collection -> aggregate(array($proj1,$sort,$proj2),$options)
```

Comment: Works, but is this fast for large collections? I doubt it, because the sort will have to know the entire collection to work. As an alternative, I'd recommend using a normalized field where the string value is stored in lower or upper case only, and potentially with replacements for characters with diacritics or for special ligature characters such as `ß` and `Æ`. That also makes it easier to search within the field, should that become a requirement.

Comment: Yes, completely agree. Since the OP didn't mention the collection size, i gave this answer. If the data is normalized, this problem would have never occured in the first place. `{allowDiskUse:true}` should help here?

Comment: I am using codeigniter library. so can you tell me how it's work with this library.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15696802/mongodb-aggregation-framework-group-by-two-fields - hope this helps.

Comment: How can i convert this in to the core php language can you give me some introduction for that..?

Comment: @HardikRanpariya - Have added the code in PHP. You can go through : http://php.net/manual/en/mongocollection.aggregate.php

Comment: thanks for this..
can you Give me some solutions i got some like this type of error.
Array
(
    [errmsg] => exception: pipeline element 0 is not an object
    [code] => 15942
    [ok] => 0
)